# jQuery.animate having hard time moving a div, right to left

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to move the box from right to left, by 50px when the Document loads.  Ive done quite a bit of searching, and im stumped.

At first I thought this would be easy to do, and I was going to be off away coding a click event into it for fun, but here I am stuck.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
    Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gameCSS.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /> 

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="media/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
    <link href="media/apple-touch-startup-image-iphone.png" media="(device-width: 320px)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image"/>
    <link href="media/apple-touch-startup-image-iphone-retina.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image"/>

    <script src="js/jgame.js"></script>

    <title>HTML</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="CREEE" />



</head>

<body>
    <div id="home" data-role="page">

    <div id="box">

    </div>


    <div id="obs">

    </div>


    </div>


</body>
```

Here is my CSS

```
#box {

width: 40px;
height: 40px;

background-color: blue;

margin: 1px;
top:10px;
position:absolute;}

#obs {width: 15px;
height: 15px;
border: solid, 2px;
background-color: red;}
```

Here is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
$('#box').animate({left: "+=50px",'slow'}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJ7V5/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this one:

```
$('#box').animate({left: "+=50px"}, 1000);
```

remove `'slow'`. [**checkout the fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/w9YE2/)

*`I am trying to move the box from right to left, by 50px when the Document loads.`*
This comment is not correct your code moves the `#box` to `left to right by 50px`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I derp'ed on the title you are correct.

Comment: This does solve the problem in the fiddle, however I think I have a linking issue.  Because when I run it locally, I dont see the results, even though the code is correct.  Thank you for your help with the code tho!

Comment: you have a missing closing `</html>` tag is it typo or you just  missed it when posting.

Comment: Jai, I really do appreciate the help.  I have confirmed that my html is loading the jgame.js file.  I used console.log("read OUT");  to confirm this.   However I am still unable to animate this block.  I have sense updatded the jsfiddle you provided me with more functions, that all work.  However, locally on my system.  I am un-able to replicate the animation.  Do you know why?